# Subform calulation error when pasting multiple records in subform

Tags: ms-access, events, subform

I do a calculation on all three Events on a subform to update the main form:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
  Me.Parent.UpdateStunden
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
  Me.Parent.UpdateStunden
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate() 
  Me.Parent.UpdateStunden
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateStunden(Optional BeforeUpdateEvent As Boolean = False)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim sql As String
Dim NewStunden As Variant

    If Me.NewRecord Then Exit Sub

    sql = _
    "SELECT Sum(Stunden) AS SumStunden " & _
    "FROM Tätigkeiten " & _
    "WHERE Tätigkeitsdatum = #" & Format(Me!Tätigkeitsdatum, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#;"

    Set rst = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenSnapshot)

    If Not rst.EOF Or Not rst.BOF Then
        NewStunden = rst!SumStunden
        If Nz(NewStunden) <> Nz(Me.Stunden) Or IsNull(Me.Stunden) Then
            Me.Stunden = NewStunden
        End If
    End If

ExitPoint:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Me.Dirty And Not BeforeUpdateEvent Then Me.Dirty = False
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err
        Case Else:  LogNTEvent Now & "Error: " & Err & ": " & Err.Description & ": UpdateStunden", EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, 1000, "Error: " & Err.Number
    End Select
    Resume ExitPoint
End Sub
```

This normally works fine.

But there is a bug if I copy and paste more than one record into the subform. When I copy and paste multiple records from one subform to the same subform but on another main-form record the calculation is wrong.

This should work as Standard because I use it everywhere.

We Need an After Paste Event!

Does anyone know how to do this?

Regards Richard

Comment: It's very hard to tell what is wrong without seeing the code you are using.

Comment: @YowE3K The problem is that pasting multiple rows is done in something like a transaction (a `Me.Requery` on AfterInsert will raise error 3246) and the data is written to the table after the `AfterInsert` event, so his query (Sum(Stunden)) doesn't have the inserted data. See his `UpdateStunden` sub below. All caused by storing calculated data.

Comment: I Need to SEE the values in the main form in Datasheet View. Thats the reason that I store the values in the main form. In Datasheet View I get an error when I use a reference to a total in the subform footer.

Comment: BitAccesser seems to have missed the point completely. If Events are there then they should work, always! In this case Events don't work because the events and the data are NOT related. An Event only makes sense when it is performed on a specific record. Here we have Events that are NOT related to a specific record. This is an Access Bug!

Also, there are also reasons when it is better to store calculated data, speed for example.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the main form value to null from the subform:

```vb
Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
    Me.Parent.Stunden = Null
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    Me.Parent.Stunden = Null
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate() 
    Me.Parent.Stunden = Null 
End Sub
```

Then use the timer:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    If IsNull(Me.Stunden) Then UpdateStunden
End Sub

Private Sub Stunden_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Dirty = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    UpdateStunden True
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateStunden(Optional BeforeUpdateEvent As Boolean = False)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim sql As String
Dim NewStunden As Variant

    If Me.NewRecord Then Exit Sub

    sql = _
    "SELECT Sum(Stunden) AS SumStunden " & _
    "FROM Tätigkeiten " & _
    "WHERE Tätigkeitsdatum = #" & Format(Me!Tätigkeitsdatum, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#;"

    Set rst = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenSnapshot)

    If Not rst.EOF Or Not rst.BOF Then
        NewStunden = rst!SumStunden
        If Nz(NewStunden) <> Nz(Me.Stunden) Or IsNull(Me.Stunden) Then
            Me.Stunden = NewStunden
        End If
    End If

ExitPoint:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Me.Dirty And Not BeforeUpdateEvent Then Me.Dirty = False
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err
        Case Else:  LogNTEvent Now & "Error: " & Err & ": " & Err.Description & ": UpdateStunden", EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, 1000, "Error: " & Err.Number
    End Select
    Resume ExitPoint
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a weird solution. First why do you store calucated values, instead of calculating them when they are needed (e.g.: in the query of the main form)? Second, the subform events fire for each record (except `AfterDelConfirm` this fires just once), if not there is something wrong with your code. Show the original code in your question, then we will find a better solution, if you absolutely need the value stored.

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste mistake. Did you check your events fireing with a `Debug.Print`or a `MsgBox`? Why don't you calculate at rumtime?

Comment: Seems like multiple rows pasting is done in something like a transaction (you can undo, if confirm record changes is activated in options). If you use a calculation in a textbox (`=Sum([Stunden])`) in the subform, it refreshes automatic, in the main form you just need a textbox with a reference to the textbox in subform (`=[subFormControl].Form![textBoxWithSum]`)

Comment: That's a condition that should have mentioned at the beginning ;) Try a unbound textbox in mainform with `=DSum("Stunden";"Tätigkeiten";"Tätigkeitsdatum = #" & Format(Me!Tätigkeitsdatum; "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#")` name ist `txtSumStunden` and then use `Me.Parent!txtSumStunden.Requery` to update the value after changes in all three subform events. Add the double datasheetview condition and [syntaxhighlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) (vba language code is `lang-vb`) to your question.

Comment: Sorry use `DomSumme("Stunden";"Tätigkeiten";"Tätigkeitsdatum = #" & Format([Me]![Tätigkeitsdatum];"jjjj-mm-tt") & "#")`. I mixed up German and English in my comment. Another hint: You can get rid of using `;` instead of `,`as separator if you change your `List Separator` in Region Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the Control-Source of the Textbox-Control on the main form to this:

```vb
=DomSumme("Stunden";"Tätigkeiten";"Tätigkeitsdatum = #" & Format([Tätigkeitsdatum];"jjjj-mm-tt") & "#")
```

And then requery after all three Events:

```vb
Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
    Me.Parent!Test.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    Me.Parent!Test.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Parent!Test.Requery
End Sub
```

N.B. German Office 2010

Comment: Add an english version to answer as most people won't be able to adapt this, because they don't know `DomSumme`(`DSum`), have to use the `,`as list seperator and don't know german date formats `"jjjj-mm-dd"`(`"yyyy-mm-dd"`).